# What has been done with this object?

Tags: modeling

[image: Blender Inset Operation]

Does anyone know what operation was done immediately after the inset operation to remove the bottom inset in the provided gif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>i</kbd> to inset then <kbd>B</kbd> for boundary (option also available in the bottom of the *Tools* panel on the left of the 3D View). By the way, is it not a Penfinity video?   ;)